# Firebase retrieving of data slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase app that loads a list of applicants. The problem is it became slow when it already loads 500+ applicant data. Before it's still fast because it loads a small number of data (eg. 100 applicants). I use this code:

```
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var applicants = [];
            // other code here
        });
        deferred.resolve(applicants);
    }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
```

I'm thinking of limiting the number of data being retrieved and paginate the data but isn't it the same? Because I need to know the number of data to be able to paginate it and therefore the retrieval would be the same.

Comment: Might just get the keys once and store it in local storage then just get the values by key (indexed)

Comment: The key to keeping your app responsive is not loading more data than the user can see. It seems unlikely that you're going to show a list of 500 applicants on a mobile screen, so I'd recommend reducing that to the actual number they will reasonably need to see. Aside from that, it's always hard to help with performance without seeing the problem in action. So if you want more feedback, can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the slow loading you see?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but `.on("value")` starts with requesting all data until it's finished. So if you have a lot of data it takes a lot of time. An alternative could be the `.on("child_added")` function which returns each child when it's added to the database. But it is also called for each element when you start calling it the first time. So "perfect" for non blocking/fast startup.

Look at the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added

```
// Retrieve new posts as they are added to our database
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var newPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log("Author: " + newPost.author);
  console.log("Title: " + newPost.title);
  console.log("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
});
```

Comment: That was what I initially thought when I started using Firebase. But on the network level there is no difference between how `value` events and `child_added` events retrieve their data. Both retrieve all initial data for the listener before they start firing events.

Comment: Thank you that is good to know. I guess I can't help you then. Sorry